# Prove that $\frac {a}{b+c} + \frac {b}{a+c}+ \frac {c} {a+b}=1$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Given $$\frac {a^2}{b+c} + \frac {b^2}{a+c}+ \frac {c^2} {a+b}=0,$$  prove that $$\frac {a}{b+c} + \frac {b}{a+c}+ \frac {c} {a+b}=1.$$

I tried but getting $\frac {a}{b+c} + \frac {b}{a+c}+ \frac {c} {a+b}=0$. How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

We should assume that $a+b+c\neq0$, for if $a+b+c=0$ and $a,b,c\neq0$, we have $a^2/(b+c)+b^2/(c+a)+c^2/(a+b)=0$ but $a/(b+c)+b/(c+a)+c/(a+b)=-3$.

Here's a somewhat *prettier* way to attack:

In order to make two quantities resemblant, we multiply $a+b+c$ to the second quantity, which yields

$$(a+b+c)\sum\frac a{b+c}=\sum\frac{a^2}{b+c}+\sum\left(\frac{ba}{b+c}+\frac{ca}{b+c}\right)=a+b+c+\sum\frac{a^2}{b+c}$$

If $a+b+c\neq0$, we can multiply $(a+b+c)^{-1}$ to both sides and the result follows.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum\frac{a^2}{b+c}=0\iff\sum\left(\frac{a^2}{b+c}+a\right)=a+b+c$$

$$(a+b+c)\sum\frac a{b+c}=a+b+c$$

$$\iff(a+b+c)\left[-1+\sum\frac a{b+c}\right]=0$$

Answer (score 1):

the term $$\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{a+c}+\frac{c}{a+b}-1=0$$ is equivalent to
$$\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3+abc}{(a+b)(b+c)(a+c)}=0$$
this is true since the equation $$\frac{a^2}{b+c}+\frac{b^2}{a+c}+\frac{c^2}{a+b}=0$$ is equivalent to
$$\frac{(a+b+c)(a^3+b^3+c^3+abc)}{(a+b)(b+c)(a+c)}=0$$
if $$a+b+c=0$$ we can plug $c=-a-b$ in $$a^3+b^3+c^3+abc=0$$ and we get $$-4ab(a+b)=0$$ and it can only $$a=0$$ therefore we get $$\frac{b^2+c^2-bc}{bc}=0$$ or in the other case we get $$\frac{a^2+c^2-ac}{ac}=0$$

Comment: Why? $a+b+c$ also can be zero.

Comment: i think it must be $a+b+c\ne 0$